# I'm using int parse same way as it is in the console application but doesn't work in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, keypress

I need some help because I can't seem to get to display the text label here. I am using Windows Form C# VS 2015. When I press enter the error is on barangay = int.Parse(lblDistrict.Text); uhm also, I am applying the same way console.readline is used but it seems that it doesn't work. Can somebody help me in the code? :) Thanks in advance

```
private void txtBarangay_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{

    int barangay = 0;
    barangay = int.Parse(lblDistrict.Text);

    if (e.KeyChar == (char)13)
    {
        if (barangay >= 1 && barangay <= 146)
        {
            lblDistrict.Text = "District 1";
        }
        else if (barangay >= 147 && barangay <= 267)
        {
            lblDistrict.Text = "District 2";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It doesn't display errors anymore but it displays nothing.

Comment: Well what's the value of `lblDistrict.Text`? What diagnostics have you performed? Have you stepped through this in the debugger? Is the handler even being called? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: the text is <district goes here>. it works on the console application using barangay = int.Parse(Console.Readline); I want to apply the same way.

Comment: I would have expected that you parse txtBarangay.Text :o)

Comment: Format Exception is handled when I parse txtBarangay

Comment: Well, that is possible, but in txtBarangay.Text you will get the input from the user. Maybe you only want to parse it, when enter is pressed?

Comment: Nope. when I pressed enter, it parses txtbarangay then if else statement then result.

Answer (score 0):

It is the matter of focus. When you press the key, which control is focused? Is it the one that you have written the `KeyPress` event for?

So you must make sure that either when the key is pressed either that specific control has the focus, or add this even to all controls.

Comment: Enter = 13 I watched it on youtube that when e.KeyChar == (char)13 is enter

Comment: Yes KeyCode of _Enter_ is 13, the problem is that the control that you have written _KeyPress_ event for, must be focused when you press _Enter_ key in order to trigger the event. And also note that focus for `Label` Controls doesn't trigger (in case the control is a label)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of Exception you get , but you must use Int.TryParse  instead of int.parse . 
check this link http://dailydotnettips.com/2016/01/16/back-to-basic-difference-between-int-parse-and-int-tryparse/

Thanks

Comment: I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

First, Please include **try-catch block** in your program in-order to catch the exception.

If the string in the textBox contains anything other than **ONLY** numbers (Example "12er"), It will throw Exception. Try **Int.TryParse** if this is the case